# How to get div without class Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I tried to get into the first div without of success

```
Elements newsHeadlines;
                newsHeadlines=doc.getElementsByClass("ms-detail");
            String st=newsHeadlines.toString();
            System.out.println(st);
```

and that the output

```
<div class="ms-detail"> 
 <div id="hello"></div> 
 <div id="lazy"></div> 
</div>
```

[Web source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEsMG.png)

I also tried first() and a lot of other things...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Check if code has been created dinamically from javacript. It is possible that the div with class ms-detail is not part of the original html

Comment: I want to get one of the section inside the div...How should I know if it part of the original htm?

Comment: Are you able to get it with CSS path? like `Elements elements = doc.select("body > div.ms-detail > ...`. Use developer tool to get CSS path _copy>copy selector_

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work. What else I can do to parse that?

Comment: Agree with @DavideLorenzoMARINO, probably just place holders for lazy loading using js scripts, so jsoup is not enough here, try HtmlUnit or any other headless browser with js support.